# Looking for key-value rich result documentation

Tags: google-search, search-results

Do you know where I can find documentation or any kind of information for key-value (under the description) SERP rich result?

I've checked Wikipedia (and other websites that give the same results) in Structured Data Testing Tool, but they don't seem to have any markup for the data shown in the search result.

[image: Google search result example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is likely being discovered from Wikidata and double-checked in the corresponding Wikipedia article.

This key-value database at Google is called the Google Knowledge Graph.